# copying file from local machine to remote server using ssh

Tags: shell

How do I copy a file from my local machine to a remote server using ssh, I have tried the following code:

```
scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -r $tarpath/$user@$server:$perfresdir/temp/ACK/
```

Answer (score 1):

SSH? You are using scp.

It goes something like this :

```
scp local_location user@target_ip:target_location.
```

Example :

```
scp /tmp/myFile.tar root@192.168.1.1:/tmp/
```

Comment: if i want to use ssh please let me know the command

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following command:

```
cat localfile | ssh target_address cat ">" remotefile
```

For example:

```
cat local.txt |ssh $user@target_ip cat ">" remote.txt
```

For more details:

http://ultra.ap.krakow.pl/~bar/DOC/ssh_backup.html